# How do I produce a cursor with NDB map

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queryclass#Query_map), the `map` function supports all query option keywords. I am, however, unable to produce the `cursor` and the `has_more` values, using map. How do you do that? If I use `fetch` to produce `result`, `cursor` and `has_more` I can no longer use `map` since it does not work on simple lists.

Answer (score 5):

You can't get a cursor out of map() -- the only way to get a cursor is to use a QueryIterator, or to call fetch_page() (which uses a QueryIterator internally).  The has_more flag is only accessible by using fetch_page().

If you have a simple list, use Python's *built-in* map() function:

```
map(<function>, <list-of-entries>)
```

But perhaps you could tell us more about what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Basically I'm loading a "page" of 20 comments and for each of those comments I want to load a "page" of 5 sub-comments (preferably in parallel). I need the cursors for both comments and sub-comments so that I can load more on demand. I have a working solution, using the serial approach, but I'm under the impression that this should be possible to do in parallel.

Comment: @guido does using Python's built-in map() function work correctly with tasklets, as query.map() does?

Comment: @robert: what would map() correctly working with tasklets even mean? It doesn't know anything about tasklets, so if you map a tasklet over a list of objects, you'll get a list of Futures back.  I'd consider that correct. :-)

Comment: @guido, I phrased that poorly. ;)   What I actually meant to ask was more subtle.  Basically, I was trying to ask and get confirmation that using the built-in map results in the tasklets being run with the same degree of "concurrency" (rpc parallelism) as using query.map.  In my code I am using fetch_page in combination with built-in map, then remapping that list calling get_result() on the futures.  It *appears* to do what I want.

Comment: Eh. :-)  Well, in almost all cases, "calling" an async method takes no time at all -- it simply constructs a Future and queues a call that runs the body of the async method later.  This is because the tasklet implementation uses a generator -- "calling" a generator immediately returns, and the function body doesn't start to execute until you call next() on it.  (Try this!)  So a map() call on a list of N values immediately gives you a list of N Futures, and as a side effect adds N callbacks to the event loop.

Comment: PS.  The optimal way to run those callbacks is actually to use yield on the *list* of Futures, that way they can maximally intermingle.  Calling get_result() N times is less optimal, especially if there may be other tasklets in flight (and there usually are -- most operations internally use additional tasklets, e.g. the cache management).  Finally, the reason I said "almost" in the first line of the previous comment because it's possible to decorate a non-generator-function with @ndb.tasklet.  Those run immediately.  (If such a function called get_result() I would have to shoot the author. :-)

Comment: Awesome, the tip about yield is *exactly* what I was wondering after poking around!  Thank you.